# How to solve this error while installing python packages in RStudio?

Tags: r

I gave the following command

> library(reticulate)
>
> py_install("pandas")

I am getting an error while installing  python packages in RStudio :

```
Solving environment: ...working... failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
Error: Error 1 occurred creating conda environment r-reticulate
```

Please help in resolving this error.

Comment: What command are you running exactly?

Comment: Looks like an issue with some SSL lib. What is the OS?

Comment: @heisenbug47, I suspect the point is to install a *python package* within RStudio (using R's `reticulate` package), not an *R package*.

Comment: @r2evans, `reticulate` package is used to execute python code in R studio or within R code as far as i know and its not used to install any package. It provides python environment within R. [Refer this](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) for more details. Python packages need to be installed as usual either via pip or conda if anconda is being used. And to use it within R, use `reticulate` and mention proper path where python packages are installed.

Comment: Huh? I was responding to your previous comment. Since you seem aware that python packages need to be installed via `pip` or `conda`, why did you suggest `install.packages()`?

Comment: @r2evans, that's probably my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Solved a similar error arising from install_tensorflow():

```
SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

by adding the path of the openssl.exe to the %PATH% environment variable of Windows. In my pc, the path is like this (replace "[username]" by yours):

```
C:\Users\[username]\Anaconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1b-he774522_1\Library\bin
```

If somehow your openssl is an old version (as discussed here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8046), you can install an up-to-date version following the guides below:

https://jchornsey.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/installing-openssl-in-windows-8-1/
https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/how-to-install-the-most-recent-version-of-openssl-on-windows-10-in-64-bit/

As these guides explain, "the official OpenSSL website offers Linux sources only." For Windows binaries, you can obtain from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html provided by Shining Light Productions. The github issue discussion mentions that this link is listed on the OpenSSL wiki (https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries -- I went there two days ago to confirm but today that page does not load, perhaps due to the Easter holidays).

The guides also explain that "If you’re not developing software, you don’t need the full versions; the “Light” version is intended for end-users.

Comment: While this answers the question, you should [edit] your answer to include the more important parts from the links at the bottom in the answer itself. This helps prevent this portion of the answer from becoming invalid if the links stop working for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Python from RStudio seems interesting. One way to go is use `reticulate`package in R which provides R interface to Python and use Python within R.

Python packages are generally installed either using `pip` or 'conda' if anaconda is being used.

Then to use it in R, mention the proper path where python is installed in the system.

```
library(reticulate)
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python")
```

`Reticulate` also provides a way to install package using `py_install()` function.

```
library(reticulate)
py_install("pandas")
```

Please look for more details about `reticulate`package [here](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) and about installing packages [here](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/python_packages.html).

Comment: That looks more of SSL/HTTP error. Is anaconda working properly in the system ?