# reticulate conda_install fails to install package from PyPI

Tags: python, ssl, pip, conda, reticulate

I'm trying to install the [`pretermgrowth` python package](https://pypi.org/project/pretermgrowth/) from PyPI with `reticulate::conda_install()` (running on Windows 10) and I'm getting the following error message:

```r
library(reticulate)
conda_create("project-env")
conda_install("project-env", "pretermgrowth")
```

```
PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - pretermgrowth

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

I have the same problem when I also try to install without conda environments `reticulate::py_install("pretermgrowth")`. For reference, I can `pip install` the package just fine.

That led me to trying to install using `pip = TRUE`, which gave me this error

```r
conda_install("neo-extrauterine-growth", "pretermgrowth", pip = TRUE)
```

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Error: Error installing package(s): "pretermgrowth"
```

I tried to follow the advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54897379/11381493) about putting specific Anaconda directories in my path, but no luck there either.

**How can I install this package using `reticulate`? Is something about the package broken?**

Comment: Is there a pretermgrowth Conda package?

Comment: Yup, it's linked in the question up top

Comment: Unless I'm looking at the wrong thing, all I see is a link to the pypi page.

Comment: Oh I just noticed you asked if it was a __conda__ package. That was one of my main questions -- is it possible to configure `reticulate` to install from PyPI? Or does it need to be a conda package for Windows?

Comment: _That was one of my main questions -- is it possible to configure reticulate to install from PyPI?_ I'm not 100% sure, my best guess is no since it's an R package, right?

Comment: Correct, it's just on PyPI

Comment: _Correct, it's just on PyPI_ Was that in response to my earlier comment (_Unless I'm looking at the wrong thing, all I see is a link to the pypi page._) ?

Comment: Haha thanks for sticking in there with me! that was in response to your earlier comment.

In response to whether or not its an R package, `pretermgrowth` is a python package, that is on pypi, that I would like to use in R.

On a separate note, I think my problem is actually an SSL issue. Though I have no problems `pip install`ing things, when I use `pip = TRUE` in `py_install()` I get a `SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")`.

Comment: From searching that error message, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54558389/how-to-solve-this-error-while-installing-python-packages-in-rstudio), which seems related.